# How to wrap the text in the DisplayFor in MVC view?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

[image: comments extends]
I am developing a MVC app.
I have a commenting feature in the app.

My problem is, when any user posts a comments without pressing the enter key, then the comment comes out as one single line and crosses the screen and the user has to scroll horizontally to see the entire comment.

I want to wrap the comment and show it at a specific width.

Ex.

> admin 04 May 13 12:43 PM
>   zxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxcasdasdzxczxca

I use the below code to show the comments in the view

```
<div class="CommentP" style="width:550px;" >
 @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText, new {style = "width:550px;" })
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your style="width:550px" do the trick? If it's too wide just change it?

Comment: No, I am expecting that comment should get fit in 550px. its come more longer, it crosses the screen.

Comment: Do you actually test using words or just one long word / string of characters?

Comment: yes...I am testing the app, I just copy paste the pattern of words, without putting enter key...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<div style="word-wrap:break-word;">` or `<div style="overflow:auto;">`